# Visual Composer challenge

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I would like to create a drop down menu inside a visual composer row which is having a background slider and on top of that my are my links which i want to toggle. The problem i am facing while editing the custom css is that the links are not being set to bottom:0; have set the postion:absolute using css hero; Inserted my JQuery inside raw JS element of Visual Composer. I have created a fiddle for the same purpose. I cant understand what is going wrong. The webpage is

[My static page](https://financebazaar.com)

Here is the jquery written inside raw JS:

```
<script>
$(".btn").click(function()
{
$(".truecomparelinks").slideToggle();
});
</script>
```

[fiddle that i want to achieve](http://jsfiddle.net/gizmopratik/mdfu3roq/)

Comment: It looks like visual composer is stripping the `<script>` tag from your code and slapping the script into your page as plain text.

Comment: it even adds a surrounding div that seems like it would normally be used to indicate a piece of javascript code visible on the page : `<div class="wpb_raw_code wpb_raw_js">`

Comment: Contact pavel@WPBakery.com provide code and we will suggest a solution for this if it is visual composer issue

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, for some reason using `jQuery` instead of `$`fixed it for me.

I start my Visual Composer JavaScript stuff with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function() {

// your code

});
</script>
```